# User relationship join in active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

My `User` table is connected to `Company` via a `user_company` table. Now I want to retrieve the company name that user belongs to. Please can you suggest the query I should use?

User
`has_many :companies, :through => :user_companies`

Company
`has_many :users, :through => :user_companies`

User does not directly belong to company.

`user.company.name` gives an error. I want to find out the company name which the user belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a user has multiple companies, it is `user.companies`. To get the names, you could do e.g. `user.companies.map(&:name)`

Answer (score 0):

`@user.companies` will give you an array of all the companies that the user is associated with.
Now, you can simply iterate over the array and get the company's name for each of the companies.

```
company_names = []
@user.companies.each {|entry| company_names << entry.name}
```

This is when you don't have the company's name attribute in the `user_companies` table.
If you have it that way, you can simply get all the names by

```
UserCompany.where(:select=>"name", :user_id=> @user)
```